# Why then doesn't keep the order of the callbacks?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I have the following code:

```
Promise
  .resolve('333')
  .then(()=>{setTimeout(()=>{Promise.resolve('123');},10000)})
  .then(()=>{console.log("should wait");});
```

I thought that the output should be first '123' and then 'should wait'. From unclear reason the 'should wait' is printed first. I thought that the second then won't start until the asynchrony function (setTimeout) won't finished. I read that this is all the "magic" of using *Promise* and *then*. Now i'm very confused. Why for example it doesn't happen when we call *fetch* function? *fetch* function is also asynchrony, so why the then after the fetch doesn't start before the *fetch* ends?

Comment: Your promise chain doesn't wait for the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a `.then` callback explicitly returns a Promise, the next `.then` in the chain is guaranteed to run nearly instantly afterwards (it gets put into the microtask queue).

Right now, you're not returning anything, so `undefined` gets returned, so the second `.then` runs immediately.

If you want the first `.then` to cause the second to wait until the timeout finishes, return a Promise that resolves when the timeout resolves:

```js
Promise.resolve('333')
    .then(() => {
        return new Promise((res) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            res('123');
          }, 3000);
        });
     })
    .then(() => { console.log("should wait 3 seconds"); });
```

Comment: does the `Promise` must wrap the `setTimeout`? Can't it be the other way: setTimeout will wrap the Promise?

Comment: No, because the value returned by the callback must be a Promise. The `.then` callback doesn't know what to do with a timeout ID. The Promise must wrap the `setTimeout`.

Comment: Is it right to say, that in my case, the promise is settled as fulfill immediately and therefore next then can start immediately ?

Comment: In your original code, the only Promise in the chain is the original one that does `Promise.resolve('333')`. The Promise inside the `.then` is not returned from the `.then`, so the next `.then` does not wait for it.